# How can I assign generator.next to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, generator

When using Javascript generators, I can do the following,

```
function* Gen() {
   while(true) console.log(yield);
} 

let gen = Gen();
gen.next('first'); // outputs 'first'
gen.next('second'); // outputs 'second'
```

Now I want pass gen.next to another function, to let that function take control of the generator. But I am getting an error.

```
let next = gen.next;
next('third'); // TypeError: Cannot read property '_invoke' of undefined
```

Is this possible? If not, why?

**Update(based on answers):**

This is possible. The error was due to the loss of scope when I assigned gen.next definition to a variable. To avoid that, I can bind the scope as,

```
let next = gen.next.bind(gen);
```

The lesson learnt here is that, iterables like generators have a scope, which is the iterable itself. It makes sense since the iterables need to maintain a state.

Comment: I've never seen `next` used like that. It's not its purpose. If you want a custom one, implement your own interator

Comment: @Adelin I get your point. But this is required for the project I am working on. Trying to add a plugin to a library which is already using generators

Comment: As you wish. You might want to read [the iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). (p.s. didn't downvote)

Comment: That actually helps. Thanks Adelin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because if you don't call `next` on an object (here `gen`), the `this` bind is not good anymore.

Calling `gen.next()` and `next()` is not the same thing in JavaScript ;) If you don't bind it, I believe `this` will be the default context (`window`).

Just bind it like that, it will work because `this` will be `gen`, even when you do not specify it:

```
let gen = Gen();
gen.next('first'); // outputs 'first'
gen.next('second'); // outputs 'second'

// Now let's see if we can assign gen.next to a variable

let next = gen.next.bind(gen);
next('third');
```

Comment: @NinaScholz It does work, just not with the codesandbox.io tool, but i don't know how to use it and it's pretty early in the morning. With JSFiddle, it works like a charm.

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda Glad that helped ;) Please mark the answer as correct if it fits your needs!

Comment: @sjahan Yeah stackoverflow doesn't let me accept until like 10-15 minutes since I posted the question.